# Discord.js: Converting a user id (string) to user id (Snowflake)

Tags: javascript, json, discord.js

Not finding any leads on how to solve this problem.

I am working on a Discord bot. Part of its functionality is storing some user records. Each user's data is indexed in a JSON file where their user id is used as the key. [When I obtain this key, it is of the Snowflake data type](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=id), but storing it in the JSON file converts it into a string.

One part of program tries to fetch a user using the user's id, which I pulled from my JSON file, therefore it is a string.

```
let clientUser = client.users.fetch(userID);
```

However, I can't do this, as fetch() [requires the user ID to be a "Snowflake" data type.](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/UserManager?scrollTo=fetch)

How can I convert my user ID from string to the Snowflake data type it is asking for?

Alternatively, is there a way to use fetch() or something comparable with a string data type instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A snowflake can be a string like the link you linked stated, if that's a valid user Id then it will work. The issue is that fetch is an async method so you can't just assign clientUser to it, when you are doing that you are assigning it a promise.

Instead you will have to either use a wait or  `.then`

```js
const clientUser = await client.users.fetch(userID);
```

or

```
client.users.fetch(userID).then(clientUser => console.log(clientUser));
```